# Perl / Apache - undefined symbol: Perl_Top_ptr

Tags: apache, perl

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10.

I compiled Apache 2.2.26 because of requirements at my workplace. Upon start, it's giving me:

```
Cannot load httpd/modules/mod_perl.so into server: libperl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I installed the lib:

```
sudo apt-get install libperl-dev
```

Upon retesting, I get the following error:

```
Cannot load httpd/modules/mod_perl.so into server: httpd/modules/mod_perl.so: undefined symbol: Perl_Top_ptr
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build mod_perl.so from the source distribution on the same machine you built apache on:

http://perl.apache.org/download/source.html

Follow the instructions for what you need mod_perl 1.0 or 2.0.

You probably need mod_perl 2.0:

http://perl.apache.org/download/source.html#Stable_mod_perl_2_0_Source_Distribution

Downloads:

http://apache.org/dist/perl/